# WAS 7.0 LDAP configuration

Tags: ldap, websphere

All,

I'm trying to configure LDAP with Websphere. I'm doing settings in "Security" area when I click on 'Test settings' I'm getting connection exception (SECJ7340E). The Ip/host are all fine but I'm not able to connect to the server. Have you come across such a situation?? Do you know the solution to this?
I'm using WAS 7.0.

Answer (score 1):

LDAP troubleshooting is not hard.

What LDAP server are you connecting too?  Does it have any logging? Can you get an error message from the LDAP server admins?  (I.e. If they see a bad bind DN, bad password error etc, then you have a much easier troubleshooting job to do).

I am sure you have the right IP.  Now what port should you be connecting too?  Clear text is 389, LDAP over SSL is 636, but they might have changed those values for some reason.

Does your LDAP server allow clear text connections at all?

Do you have SSL configured correctly?  Generally this means that whatever system you are using, its trusted root keystore should include the public key of the CA that signed the server cert used by the LDAP server.  (I.e. Versign, Thwate)  Possibly it is using a self signed certificate, in which case you should get an export of the CA that minted its public key to import into your keystore.

Webshpere is Java based, so I imagine it is using the the Java Keystore facility.  Use the keytool executable in the Java bin directory to add the trusted root to the keystore WebSphere is using.  (That detail I leave to you).

What Bind DN are you using?  Is it a real correct LDAP DN to connect with?

Use an LDAP browser like ApacheDS and see what it takes to connect to the LDAP server to validate the settings.